# MySQL how to preserve precisions when using division?

Tags: php, mysql, precision, division, bcmath

Let us say we have values we've retrieved in the tables, these values are strings so it's fine to divide them. We have this kind of report, but I don't like to handle it thru a Programming Language, yet to run it thru 1 sql query to retrieve all reports.

To make the query short for asking here, take a look at below simple mysql query.

```
select "68078004281240001301" / "1000000000000000000" from {a dummy table};
```

The above returns a value `68.07800428124`, and we are lossing `0001301` in the decimal point.

Already tried `FORMAT()` or `ROUND()` yet not working, or I missed some mysql functions?

---

But when using bcmath in PHP, we could do it like this

```
$n = '68078004281240001301';
$d = '1000000000000000000';
bcdiv($n, $d, strlen($d) - 1);
```

and the value above will give us an exact precision we want `68.078004281240001301`

---

Please remember that I am going to use this for reporting along with filters later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the difficulty is that as your dividing two strings - which are actually integers, it doesn't know the type of values to use (as in precision).  If you instead cast the values to the [decimal type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html), you can force it to work to any precision (up to 65 digits)...

```
select "68078004281240001301" / "1000000000000000000", cast("68078004281240001301" as decimal(60,30))/ cast("1000000000000000000" as decimal(60,30))
```

gives...

```
"68078004281240001301" / "1000000000000000000"
68.07800428124

cast("68078004281240001301" as decimal(60,30))/ cast("1000000000000000000" as decimal(60,30))
68.078004281240001301000000000000
```

Comment: This is perfect!